# my span tag doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, html, joomla

i have a span tag . which has to work as a reserve button. it also check whether it is reserved befor or not . to show another image for the span .see the code :

```
       <span class="btnrsv" <?php if   ($row_Recordset1['status'] == 'Free' || $row_Recordset1['status'] == 'Reserved' ) echo 'style="cursor: pointer;"';  ?> onclick="$('ap_id').value='<?php echo $row_Recordset1['ap_id']; ?>';<?php 
   if ($row_Recordset1['status'] == 'Reserve') echo 'if (alertbox()) $(\'adminForm\').submit();  '; 
   else if ($row_Recordset1['status'] != 'sold') echo ' $(\'adminForm\').submit(); '; ?> "  >
       <?php
    if   ($row_Recordset1['status'] == 'Free')    echo '<img src="'.JURI::base().'components/'.JRequest::getVar('option').'/assets/images/free.png"/>';
    else if ($row_Recordset1['status'] == 'Reserve')   echo '<img src="'.JURI::base().'components/'.JRequest::getVar('option').'/assets/images/reserved.png"/>';
    else echo '<img src="'.JURI::base().'components/'.JRequest::getVar('option').'/assets/images/sold.png"/>';
        ?>   
   </span>
```

Comment: The person who allowed scriplet to be embedded in HTML should be shot.

Comment: But not murdered. Just shot in the hand so that the person is forever prevented from writing any further code.

Comment: If you're using Joomla 2.5+ then replace `JRequest` as it's deprecated

Comment: why should he be shot ?? :))

Comment: and what do u mean bu replacing Jrequest ???